# nginx error_page redirect retaining header

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers

I am trying to write an nginx configuration for authentication, but I am unsure of how to retain headers when using a 302 redirect.

Below is an example of how the server is setup.

```
location / {
    #send to /auth/ for authentication
    request_auth /auth/;
    #upon failure, redirect to login
    error_page 401 404 = @noaccess;

    ...
}

location @noaccess {
    return 302 /login/;
}

location /auth/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    #The header set here is what I would like to retain
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}

location /login/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    #by the time 302 redirect, $request_uri is no longer the original...
    proxy_set_header X-Target $request_uri;
}
```

Essentially all requests to the server must first be authenticated in the `/auth/` location. This location will generally possess the `$request_uri` that I care about in its sub request. However, whenever the `requeset_auth` directive fails, and we are redirected with the `@noaccess` location, nginx makes a new request to `/login/`.
Is there a way for me to retain the original `$request_uri` such that it is sent as a header to the `/login/` location? (this is needed in order to do a redirect later upon successful authentication).

I've seen some users talk about the `auth_request_set` [directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html?&_ga=2.139715891.1825285185.1650915375-1461016179.1649779459#auth_request_set), but I honestly do not understand how to use it effectively and how the headers of the sub request are renamed or made available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With cookies.
Browser state is managed with cookies, so you need to be sending a `Set-Cookie` header with the 302 that has $request_uri and then convert the cookie to a header in the /login/ location.

Comment: do you have an example of how that would look like? 
I am still very new with nginx